# How to transform selected columns to Map in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

This is very specific question
I have a table and I selected out one String column and two Timestamp Columns and collected them into a list with the format of List[(String,Timestamp,Timestamp)], I want to convert it to a Map with format like Map[String, ArrayList(Timestamp, Timestamp)] since one string can have multiple corresponding Timestamp values. But I don't know how to transfer it in Spark/Scala, I've tried the following codes, but not working:

```
def listToMap(input:List[(String,Timestamp,Timestamp)]) :util.HashMap[String,util.ArrayList[Timestamp,Timestamp]]= {
var out = new util.HashMap[String,util.ArrayList[Timestamp,Timestamp]]()
for (value<-input) {
  val array=new util.ArrayList[Timestamp,Timestamp](value(1),value(2))
  out.put(value(0),array)
  }
}
```

Is anyone know what's the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a breakpoint to find out how your code works where  `out.put(value(0), array).`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code: ArrayBuffer is the equivalent of ArrayList in Scala.

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val lst = List(("Test1","Timestamp1","Timestamp2"),("Test2","Timestamp3","Timestamp4"))
println(lst.map(x=>x._1 ->ArrayBuffer(x._2,x._3)).toMap)
```

> Output:

```
Map(Test1 -> ArrayBuffer(Timestamp1, Timestamp2), Test2 -> ArrayBuffer(Timestamp3, Timestamp4))
```